# Разные маршруты с помощью Google Maps Api

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Интересует вопрос, можно ли построить несколько маршрутов (не обязательно с одним концом или началом), используя Google Maps Api, в приложении под Android? Если можно, то не подскажите каким способом или где можно найти пример? 
P.S. У гугла спрашивал =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Например, используя вот это [решение](https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2)

Обратите внимание в классе Route через makeUrl можно передать 4 мода: driving, walking, bicycling, transit. Собственно на google maps проложите их разным цветом. Думаю, разберетесь